# Why is my Forge Design Automation Activity iLogic Failing?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I'm running a DA job based on a code sample, and some of my ilogic rules seem to be causing it to fail. Originally, these were running fine, but when I translated the results on the MD API, some components were still visible despite being suppressed in the result output. I went through the top level rules and solved this by setting components to visible=false, which solved the problem for the most part. After I went through my sub assemblies, I tested the ilogic, then uploaded the latest version.

Now I'm getting errors in the ilogic processing portion of the DA (If I run the logic manually with my activity, I don't get an error until the DA's iLogic processor). I tried adding try catches to the visibility lines within the ilogic to no avail. I also can't identify which rules or components are causing the issue.

Furthermore, it seems like the ilogic is trying to run at the end of the activity execution, after the results are zipped - is this right?

This is the log output:

```
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting BridgeConfig to "3 Station"
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 :  params: TunnelVisibility, false
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Setting TunnelVisibility to false
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Getting full file name of assembly
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : ** Saving SVF
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF Translator addin is available
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF Translator addin is available
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF save
[02/18/2020 19:38:02]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF files are oputput to: T:\Aces\Jobs\bcc3160360d84b849acae7443caaf428\inputFile\Playset\SvfOutput
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : SVF can be exported.
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : ** Saved SVF as T:\Aces\Jobs\bcc3160360d84b849acae7443caaf428\inputFile\Playset\SvfOutput\result.collaboration
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Zipping up T:\Aces\Jobs\bcc3160360d84b849acae7443caaf428\viewable.zip
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Zipping the following files:
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Saved as T:\Aces\Jobs\bcc3160360d84b849acae7443caaf428\viewable.zip
[02/18/2020 19:38:05]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Saving updated assembly
[02/18/2020 19:38:08]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Zip path: T:\Aces\Jobs\bcc3160360d84b849acae7443caaf428\inputFile\Playset
[02/18/2020 19:38:08]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Zipping up T:\Aces\Jobs\bcc3160360d84b849acae7443caaf428\result.zip
[02/18/2020 19:38:08]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Zipping the following files:
[02/18/2020 19:38:08]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : HeartBeating every 50000ms.
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Saved as T:\Aces\Jobs\bcc3160360d84b849acae7443caaf428\result.zip
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Ending HeartBeat
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Performing iLogic diagnostics...
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]  Context: RuleRunning 
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]  Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at Inventor.ComponentOccurrence.set_Visible(Boolean )
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at iLogic.ComponentInRule.set_Visible(Object componentName, Boolean value)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at ThisRule.Main()
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Error: 0 : iLogic error 
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]  Context: RuleRunning 
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]  Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at Inventor.ComponentOccurrence.set_Visible(Boolean )
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at iLogic.ComponentInRule.set_Visible(Object componentName, Boolean value)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09] P r o c e s s i n g   f a i l e d 
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]  
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at ThisRule.Main()
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at Autodesk.iLogic.Exec.AppDomExec.ExecRuleInAssembly(Assembly assem)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]    at iLogic.RuleEvalContainer.ExecRuleEval(String execRule)
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : End of iLogic diagnostics...
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : Deactivating plug-in: UpdateUserParametersPlugin
[02/18/2020 19:38:09]     InventorCoreConsole.exe Information: 0 : : UpdateUserParametersPlugin: deactivating... 
[02/18/2020 19:38:09] [SBXMSG] The process 2184 ended.
[02/18/2020 19:38:09] [SBXMSG] Process exit code: -1
[02/18/2020 19:38:10]  
[02/18/2020 19:38:10] End Inventor Core Engine standard output dump.
[02/18/2020 19:38:10] Error: InventorCoreConsole.exe exits with code -1 which indicates an error.
[02/18/2020 19:38:10] End script phase.
[02/18/2020 19:38:10] Error: An unexpected error happened during phase CoreEngineExecution of job.
[02/18/2020 19:38:10] Job finished with result FailedExecution
[02/18/2020 19:38:10] Job Status:
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample model that can be used to reproduce the issue? Also would need the parameters that you are changing and to what value to drive the model?
Concerning the log: some of the messages might be logged in the report.txt out of the actual order of execution

Answer (score 0):

I tried an alternative of setting visibility to off in the in the activity rather than via iLogic and found this failed as well. The work around I landed on was deleting the suppressed components, which isn't a long term solution, but at least my models look right in the viewer.

I would love to know if there's something else I'm missing or if this is the entire cause of the issue, re: the model derivative API translating/exporting suppressed components.